# the constructor HomeActivity.SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager) is undefined

Tags: android

How to resolve this issue?
i am unable to resolve this error.I think there is something missing in imports .Please give me some idea.

```
    package me.kashyap.masking.masking;

    import java.util.Locale;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.ActionBar;

    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
   public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements   ActionBar.TabListener {

       /**
        * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
        * fragments for each of the sections. We use a {@link   FragmentPagerAdapter}
          * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this
         * becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
         * {@link android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
         */
        SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

        /**
         * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
         */
        ViewPager mViewPager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

            // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the   three
            // primary sections of the activity.
            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new   SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

            // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
            mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrolled(int position,
                            float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                    }
                });
            setTabs();
         }

          private void setTabs() {
            final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }

        /**
         * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding   to
         */
        public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below).
               return BaseFragment.newInstance(position);
           }

        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager() ` my friend

Comment: where i implement this line

Comment: `mSectionsPagerAdapter = new   SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());`

Comment: Thanks a lot Neil .i resolve it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the `Context` inside

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new   SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
```

instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: Check whether you've imported all required support libraries

Comment: I resolve error by adding 'getSupportFragmentManager()'